# How to decide whether a given point is inside or outside a given cone?

Tags: convex-cone

Given a cone defined by peak point $(X_0,Y_0,Z_0)$, bottom point $(X_1,Y_1,Z_1)$ and radius $R$, how can I decide whether a given point $(X',Y'Z')$ is inside the cone?

[image]

Cone is not parallel to $XY$ plane. Cone can be at any angles based on peak point and bottom point. Could anyone please provide a solution?

Comment: radius? How does a cone have a radius?

Comment: This is not a cone in the mathematical sense. In any event, there are equations that describe the object and a point lines in the object **iff** it satisfies all of the constituent equations.

Comment: Can you give us some context? What have you tried? Hint: project $P=(X', Y', Z')$ onto the line defined by $(X_0, Y_0, Z_0)$ and $(X_1, Y_1, Z_1)$ and check the position of the projection and the distance of $P$.

Comment: Find the axis of the cone and see if the angle that the ray from the apex to the point makes with the axis is less than the cone’s angle. You can do this with dot products.

Comment: @user251257: I need to check point P=(X′,Y′,Z′)P=(X′,Y′,Z′)  is inside or outside a cone with apex is at  (X0,Y0,Z0)  and base point is at (X1,Y1,Z1). How can I check?

Comment: @amd : I think your suggestion will work for my case... I will check.   Thank You

Comment: If you really only want one nappe of the cone, then you’ll also need to examine the sign of the dot product. If the cone also has finite extent, as you’ve pictured it, the dot product again will let you test for that distance as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the cone have "peak" $(0,0,0)$, "bottom" $(0,0,1)$ and "radius" $1$, as illustrated below

[image]

Any other cone can be mapped to the cone above via an affine transformation. The candidate point must be transformed as well, of course.

Let the (affinely transformed) candidate point be $(x,y,z)$. If $z < 0$ or $z > 1$, we then immediately conclude that it is *outside* the cone. If $x^2 + y^2 > 1$, we again conclude that it is *outside* the cone. If $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq z \leq 1$$ then the candidate point is **inside** the cone. The difficulty is in finding the affine transformation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply